# rspec custom matcher is not working - getting NoMethodError

Tags: rspec, nomethoderror, matcher

I am trying to do exercise 2 in chapter 8 of Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial.org. I have added the following to the spec/support/utilities.rb file:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_title do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('title', text: message)
  end
end
```

In my authentication_pages_spec.rb file, I have changed

```
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
```

to

```
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
```

I was expecting this to work fine but when running the test I get this error message:

Authentication signin with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title('Sign in') }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_title?' for #<Capybara::Session>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:22:in`block (4 levels) in '

I cannot see why it is complaining that there is no method when I believe I have written the method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I restarted the local server and the spork thing (which I still don't fully understand), and it started working. Sorry.

Comment: Are your tests passing? Also, Capybara 2.1 will have a have_title method, just FYI http://www.elabs.se/blog/60-introducing-capybara-2-1#asserting_against_the_page_title

Comment: As of June 2014 I'm also doing the same exercise and getting the same error, although in other part of it. And, unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me.